# How can I make DataOutputStream write a bool or integer to a txt file?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, dataoutputstream

```
public static void outputFile() {
    HabitItem it;
    try {
        File path = new File("output.txt");
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fout);
        while (!stackHabitItems.isEmpty()) {
            it = stackHabitItems.pop();
            dos.writeChars("<\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if (it.isDayCompleted[i]) {
                    dos.writeInt(1);
                }
                else {
                    dos.writeInt(0);
                }
            }
            dos.writeChars("\n");

            dos.writeInt(it.id);

            dos.writeChars("\\>\n");
        }
        fout.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open file output.txt");
    }
}
```

All I'm trying to do is write an array of booleans and an integer into a file enclosed by < />

My file might look like this (assuming one iteration)
    <
    1
    0
    1
    0
    0
    0
    1
    42
    >

But the dos.writeInt is failing to produce normal output. Instead it displays
     < 
   
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
     > 
**Where the blank spaces are filled by Squares**

Why does my code not work? I feel like I'm using DataOutputStream correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `PrintStream` or your `FileOutputStream`directly instead and it will produce human readable results.

You could try like this (might still need separators between `int`s)

```
public static void outputFile() {
    File path = new File("output.txt");
    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(path);
          PrintWriter dos = new PrintWriter(fout)) {
        while (!stackHabitItems.isEmpty()) {
            HabitItemit = stackHabitItems.pop();
            dos.println("<");
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if (it.isDayCompleted[i]) {
                    dos.print(1);
                }
                else {
                    dos.print(0);
                }
            }
            dos.println();

            dos.print(it.id);

            dos.println("\\>");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to open file output.txt");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it!

Comment: 'DataOutputStream' has nothing to do with serialization.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make `DataOutputStream` write a bool or integer to txt file?

You can't. Booleans and integers are primitive data types. You can *either* write them as *binary* with `DataOutputStream` to a *binary* file, *or* write them as `Strings` to a text file with a `Writer` and constructions such as `writer.write(""+bool)`.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot more sense now!